# How to generate plot of pdf of Log Logistic Erlang random variable

Tags: r, plot, distribution

g(x) is how the pdf is defined, and parameter values are shown in the picture.
[image: image of pdf formula]

[image: table of parameter values]

I want to generate the plots corresponding this pdf using those parameters in R. I did search for a couple of examples but all I found were well-known random variables.